# Mod rewrite refer 500 internal error error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have written an rewrite rule for a folder in my website.

its looks like this :

```
#page rewrites
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/note $1/addednote_file.php [NC,L]
```

as my htaccess rule above, if any of my folders on my root directory has the addednote_file.php can be accessed by "/notes".

**This script works fine,**

But when i try to access that file with and, if that folder doesn't exist on my root directory give my 500 internal server error.

in a example this link "myweb/test/events" . "/test/ is the folder and it is exist on my root directory. but "myweb/notexist/events" . "/notexists/" is a folder and it doesn't exists on my root. and when i access this link "myweb/notexist/events" it display 500 internal server erro instead of showing my erro page.

my errodocuments are like this :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /myweb/page-couldnt-fine-reporting.php
ErrorDocument 403 /myweb/page-couldnt-fine-reporting.php
ErrorDocument 304 /myweb/page-couldnt-fine-reporting.php
```

please tell me how to add this error to my erro document
.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get a 500 error code there should be something in the error log. If there is nothing then it is the PHP that is being executed and crashing.

The second argument to `ErrorDocument` is the HTTP return code. So you can use `ErrorDocument 500` to override the default page.

If you do get something in the error log then add it to your question. You should also consider adding mod_rewrite logging in order to see what is going on. Details on how to do this are here as it is different in Apache v2.2 and v2.4:http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteLog